# Forward exit code in bash if

Tags: git, bash, if-statement

I want to run a command on bash that shows the output of `git status`, but only if something interesting is there. In other words: If everything is fine, I don't want the command to print anything. Basically I can achieve this by running:

```
if [[ $(git status -s) ]]; then git status; fi
```

The trick here is that the `-s` flag only outputs anything if there is something interesting, so it does exactly what I want to :-)

The only drawback is that if I run this in a directory that is not a git directory, I don't get an exit code not equal to `0`. If I run `git status` or `git status -s` directly, both fail with exit code `128`. But as soon as I do this within the `if`, the exit code is `0`.

How can I enhance my script so that the exit code will be forwarded?

Comment: What exit code does `git status -s` give if nothing interesting has happened?

Comment: It returns `0`, but the output itself is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the exit status check within `[[` too:

```
if [[ -n $(git status -s 2>/dev/null) ]]; then git status; fi
```

Comment: or just `if git status -s 2>/dev/null;then git status`

Comment: Does `git status -s` return true even if nothing of interest has happened then?

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect to /dev/null and check if the output is empty or not:

```
[ -n "$(git status -s 2>/dev/null)" ] && git status
```

This will perform `git status` when the `git status -s` command runs successfully and its output is not empty, as per `man test`:

```
   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work: It correctly forwards the exit code, but does not suppress output if there is nothing interesting to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rev-parse` in case the directory in not in `git`:

```
git rev-parse 2>/dev/null && { git status -s || git status; }
```